# Displaying and Inputting Values in Rows in Reactive Forms Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular-reactive-forms

The "this.orders" is the result of the API below. My problem is how can I get the material.name under the material_purchase_orders and edit just its quantity. Your solution is right. I just can't get this material.name and its quantity to be edited.

> ts

```
 this.route.paramMap
   .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => 
      this.purchaseOrderService.getOrder(+params.get('id')))
        .subscribe(
          (order:any) => {
            this.orders = order;
            console.log(order);
            this.loading = false;
         },
         error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.loading = false;
          }) 

      };




this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      rows: this.fb.array([])
  })

initGroup() {
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    rows.push(this.fb.group({
      prod_id: [null, Validators.required],
      quantity: [null, Validators.required],
    }))
  }
```

> JSON

```
{
  "id": 11,
  "reference": "pek567",
  "supplier_id": 1,
  "user_id": 1,
  "project_id": 5,
  "total": 100,
  "transaction_date": "2017-10-08",
  "created_at": "2017-10-31 13:10:44",
  "updated_at": "2017-10-31 13:10:44",
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "email": "john@gmail.com",
    "created_at": "2017-10-26 07:32:53",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-26 11:58:44"
  },
  "supplier": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Not Available",
    "address": "Not Available",
    "city": "Not Available",
    "contact_number": "Not Available",
    "created_at": "2017-10-26 16:12:22",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-26 16:12:22"
  },
  "material_purchase_orders": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "material_id": 49,
      "purchase_order_id": 11,
      "quantity": 1,
      "unit": "pcs",
      "price": 100,
      "created_at": "2017-10-31 13:10:44",
      "updated_at": "2017-10-31 13:10:44",
      "material": {
        "id": 49,
        "sku": "D16789",
        "name": "Door",
        "created_at": "2017-10-26 03:33:06",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-26 03:33:06"
      }
    }
  ],
  "user_name": "John"
}
```

Comment: How does your ts look like? How does your data look like?

Comment: @AJT_82. Pls check updated code above. My data is just an array of products. It's supposed to be on the *ngFor in the <t>r but i can't iterate two *ngFor in the <tr>. So  i put the "products *ngFor" on the <select> but that is not what i want. Its supposed to be on the <tr>

Comment: @AJT_82. I've also added a picture of what  i want to appear.  There you can see the lists of product name. The lists of product name comes from "the let product of products". The quantity also comes the products iteration but you can edit it in the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data looks like this:

```ts
obj = {material_purchase_orders: [{material: {id: 1, name: 'material1'}, quantity:2}, ..]}

// call this when you have your data
this.patchValues();

// this is where you store your data from api
productsFromApi = [];

patchValues() {
  let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
  this.obj.material_purchase_orders.forEach(material => {
    rows.push(this.fb.group({material_name: material.material.name, quantity: material.quantity}))
  })
}
```

Then you just remove the iteration of `products` from your view, and instead display the values from the formarray:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of myForm.controls.rows.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>{{row.value.material_name}}</td>
    <td><input type="number" class="col-md-6" formControlName="quantity"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t94syl?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks. But this is how can i get the data from materials. 
 *ngFor="let material of orders.material_purchase_orders"
 {{material.material.name}}. Can you help me display this?

Comment: and what is orders? You have no such thing in your code. That is why I asked how your data look likes.

Comment: Sorry @AJT_82. That is just a sample code. I've added a second picture above of my api. orders is the first Object in my picture. There you can find the material_purchase_orders inside of it

Comment: Yes the material.name inside the material_purchase_orders

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Please also, if someone asks for your data, copy paste the **JSON** instead of adding picture. If someone wants to debug your code and create a demo, the JSON can easily be copied. Now I had to write my own response (hopefully I got it right!) :)

Comment: I'm sorry about this. I still have a problem. I have  this.route.paramMap
   .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => 
      this.purchaseOrderService.getOrder(+params.get('id')))
        .subscribe(
          (order:any) => {
            this.orders = order;
            console.log(order);
            this.loading = false;
         },
         error => {
            alert("ERROR");
            console.log(error);
            this.loading = false;
          }) 

      };

Comment: And material_purchase_orders is under this.orders

Comment: I've added the route.params in the above code edited

Comment: Please fork my Stackblitz and showcase the issue you are now facing. Help me help you :)

Comment: I'll just update the JSON and my code above. Hold on

Comment: Please just take the stackblitz and fork it and make a demo of what is happening in your code right now. I don't have time to make routing and other stuff work in the demo, and it's not really my job ;) As said, help me help you :)

Comment: I've edited my question and updated the JSON file. I'm sorry i didn't fork your stackblitz. Hope you understand. Thanks a lot sir

Comment: So what is exactly the problem now? You mentioned something about the route params, is there a problem there? If so, what error are you getting?

Comment: There's no error in route.params. I just mentioned it because it has the result of the "this.orders". The "this.orders" has the API response. Can you check my edited question above. I've made it clearer :)

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, it's just about changing the `obj` name I have in demo, to `orders` instead? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t94syl?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This is an async issue, make sure you are calling `patchValues()` from within the callback `(order:any) => {
            this.orders = order;
            this.patchValues();
         },`

Comment: I just put this.patchValues() inside the ngOninit(). Its working now. Thanks a lot for the time and effort. Appreciated it a lot. God Bless you sir

Comment: It's MUCH safer to call it inside the callback, what if your request takes 5 seconds before `this.orders` has data, then you will get the same error when having the method in OnInit. Having it inside the callback (subscribe), data will for sure be in `this.offers`. But you are very welcome, glad we figured it out!